# Rails eager loading associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models `MSellingStaff` and `MPosition`

```
#m_selling_staff.rb

class MSellingStaff < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :m_position
end

#m_position.rb

class MPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key ='pos_id'
  has_many :m_selling_staffs, :foreign_key => 'emp_pos_id'
end
```

I have an attribute `pos_short_name` in `m_position`. When I try

```
@sellers = MSellingStaff.includes(:m_position).all
@sellers.first.pos_short_name
```

I am getting

> undefined method `pos_short_name' for #MSellingStaff:0x0000000651a5d0

and when I try

```
@sellers.first.m_position.pos_short_name
```

I am getting

> undefined method `pos_short_name' for nil:NilClass

In the rails console I can see that the SQL generated for

```
@sellers = MSellingStaff.includes(:m_position).all
```

is

> MSellingStaff Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "m_selling_staffs".* FROM
>   "m_selling_staffs"   MPosition Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "m_position".*
>   FROM "m_position" WHERE "m_position"."pos_id" IN ('')

What am i doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: "undefined method `pos_short_name' for nil:NilClass" indicates that @sellers.first.m_position is nil -- in other words, you have instances of MSellingStaff that do not have an associated MPosition

Comment: @DavidAldridge thats the strange thing, all values in `emp_pos_id` column of `m_selling_staffs` are there in `pos_id` column of `m_position`

Comment: you should have `pos_id` in `m_selling_staffs` table and it should refer to `m_position` according to your relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add the `foreign_key` and `class_name` to `MSellingStaff` model.

```
class MSellingStaff < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :m_position, :foreign_key => 'emp_pos_id', :class_name => "MPosition" 
end



class MPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key ='pos_id'
  has_many :m_selling_staffs, :foreign_key => 'emp_pos_id'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below

```
@sellers.first.m_position.pos_short_name
```

This is because pos_short_name is in m_position model

Comment: It means that @sellers.first.m_position does not exists

Answer (score 0):

You should move 
`:foreign_key => 'emp_pos_id'` 
to belongs_to relation.